# How does Captain Jack Harkness become the Face of Boe?

Tags: doctor-who, jack-harkness

Based off the question "[Is there anything beyond subtle hints that Jack becomes the Face of Boe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49135/is-there-anything-beyond-subtle-hints-that-jack-becomes-the-face-of-boe)"

How does Captain Jack Harkness become the Face of Boe?

Comment: Specify, please. Are you asking why he becomes known by that name? Are you asking how he became immortal? Or are you asking why he looks like a big face in a tank?

Comment: I've wondered how as well. Like did he look at himself one day and give it "hmmm, my face is getting very big but it looks like my limbs are going to fall off. I'd better get a glass tank and some carers because I might spend thousands of years in this condition"

Comment: AFAIK there's nothing canon that confirms that Jack is the Face of Boe

Comment: Other than Jack saying "The Face of Boe, they called me.".